# Issue securig MultiTenant Application with Identity Server & SaasKit

Tags: token, access-token, identityserver4, multi-tenant

I've created a multitenant ASP.NET Core Web API and secured by Identity Server. I've used SaasKit Multitenancy nugget for multitenancy. and multi-tenancy is working fine. I'm facing issue with the authentication.

I've used the different hostname for the different tenant. I've defined different scope per tenant and retrieve token based on the scope for the tenant. The first request to the API works fine. but then when the second tenant tries to access the API it errors out with audience validation. Token has the valid audience but the Web API still use the audience of the first request.

Here is the code in my API:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOptionsMonitor<IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions>, IdentityServerTenantProvider>();

        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
   {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
   });
```

And here is the implementation of IdentityServerTenantProvider

```
protected override IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions Create(IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions options, string name, string tenant, string tenantHostName)
    {
        var currentTenantContext = this._memoryCache.Get(tenantHostName) as TenantContext<PaperSaveAPITenant>;

        options.Authority = currentTenantContext.Tenant.Authority;
        options.ApiName = currentTenantContext.Tenant.ApiName;
        return base.Create(options, name, tenant, tenantHostName);
    }
```

For tenant 2, it is setting proper API Name and Authority but still while validating the token API uses the API name of the first tenant.

Comment: Did you able to resolve your issue? I am also working on IdentityServer + Multi-tenant application. Please share more information if you able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to resolve it using following code.

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        jwtOptions =>
        {
        },
        referenceOptions => {
        });
```

And then registering the IOptionMonitor for JwtBearerOptions (for JWT Tokens) & OAuth2IntrospectionOptions (For Reference Tokens). I used both because my API support both type of tokens. (Reference & JWT). If you are using only one of the then you don't need to specify both.

```
services.AddSingleton<IOptionsMonitor<JwtBearerOptions>, JWTOptionsProvider>();
services.AddSingleton<IOptionsMonitor<OAuth2IntrospectionOptions>, OAuth2IntrospectionOptionsProvider>();
```

and you need to create to class "JWTOptionsProvider" inherit from  TenantOptionsProvider & "OAuth2IntrospectionOptionsProvider" inherit from TenantOptionsProvider